# XQuery: map to array of sequences

Tags: xquery

I have the following map:

```
let $input := map { 'a-key': 'a-value', 'b-key': ['b-value-1', 'b-value-2'] }
```

(the length of the `b-key` array can vary, or be absent; `a-key` can be present or absent)

I need to create the following array:

```
[ ('a', 'b', 'b'), 'a-value', 'b-value-1', 'b-value-2' ]
```

The number of `b`s in the first sequence should correspond to the number of `b-value`s.

I've tried just about every combination of iterating/map:for-each, etc., and the array either ends up with too much nesting or completely flat...

(n.b. the array is to be passed to a function -- not mine!-- using `fn:apply`, so needs to be in this form)

Answer (score 2):

It seems hard to build an array containing a sequence that is constructed dynamically, I think you first need to construct the sequence into a variable and then use the square bracket array constructor `[$seq]` to construct the array with the sequence as the single item. Then you can `array:join` the other values:

```
let $input := map { 'a-key': 'a-value', 'b-key': ['b-value-1', 'b-value-2'] }
let $seq := ($input?a-key!'a', (1 to array:size($input?b-key))!'b')
return 
    array:join(([$seq], array {$input?a-key, $input?b-key?* }))
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbUY4ku/2

Answer (score 2):

If you are comfortable with the functional-programming side of XQuery, you can create the whole output in two nested "loops" (i.e. [`fold`s](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-fold-left)), one over the keys and the other one over those values that are arrays:

```
(: the input :)
let $input := map { 'a-key': 'a-value', 'b-key': ['b-value-1', 'b-value-2'] }

(: utility function that adds a single key/value pair to the output array :)
let $update-arr :=
    function($arr, $k, $v) {
      array:append(array:put($arr, 1, ($arr(1), $k)), $v)
    }

(: nested folds over keys and values :)
return fold-left(map:keys($input), [()], function($arr, $key) {
  let $k := substring-before($key, '-key')
  let $val := $input($key)
  return typeswitch($val)
    case array(*)
      return array:fold-left($val, $arr, function($arr2, $v) {
        $update-arr($arr2, $k, $v)
      })
    default
      return $update-arr($arr, $k, $val)
})
```

You can even abbreviate the `array(*)` case as `return array:fold-left($val, $arr, $update-arr(?, $k, ?))` if you want.

The result is `[("a", "b", "b"), "a-value", "b-value-1", "b-value-2"]` as expected.